# Form Based Authentication redirecting to blank page

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am trying to implement form based authentication for an existing J2EE application. In my web.xml file, I have:

```
    <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/content/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/content/LoginFailure.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

And a security constraint:

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin-access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

My homepage is at:

```
(http://localhost:8080/leagueWAR/MainLeaguePage.html)
```

On my homepage, I have an href that references an html file that is inside the admin directory (the admin directory is at the same level as the homepage):

```
<li><a href="./admin/TestAdmin.html">SH League ADMIN</a></li>
```

When I click the link, I am taken to:

```
https://localhost:8443/shLeagueWAR/admin/TestAdmin.html
```

As I would expect, but the page it renders is blank??

Comment: This is probably caused by some error in `/WEB-INF/content/Login.jsp`. It may help if you post the code in it.

Comment: Anything on the server console?